# How to convert tbb concurrent_hash_map to regular std::map?

Tags: c++, concurrenthashmap, tbb

I am working on some concurrent program and don't know how to convert `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` to regular `std::map` or get values, stored in the concurrent map in another way.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it the naive way, iterating the hashmap and adding the items to the std::map in the loop.

Comment: What happens if an erase operation by another thread invalidates an iterator just before it's dereferenced?  It's not clear (to me at least) that `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` protects against that?

Comment: I use map iterating to write results, i.e in main thread, in thread you should use mac accessor and find method. This method gives protection from the situation, you mentioned.

Comment: @G.M. `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` does not provide safe iterators, i.e., you may only iterate a concurrent_hash_map if it is guaranteed that it will not be altered as long as you the iterators are in use.

Comment: @mpoeter Thanks, that's what I thought.  In which case this answer is incorrect.